# HF Digital Mode Band Plan for the USA

Tags: united-states, hf, band-plan, digital-modes, modes

I recently started playing with the digital modes, but have been frustrated with the difficulty in finding where certain modes are commonly used. Is there a digital mode band plan for the HF bands, to the level of which modes are commonly used on what frequencies?

I live in the United States.

Comment: http://www.ciarc.org/downloads/Digital_Mode_Band_Plan.pdf

This resource may help someone more knowledgeable form an answer

Comment: Where in the world are you located? If nothing else, the answer will depend heavily on which region you belong to, since the frequency allocations to amateur radio differ between parts of the world. (For example, the US and Europe have *very* different 80 and 40 meter band allocations.)

Comment: Since you've accepted an answer that isn't specific to the US, please consider editing your question to more accurately represent the information you need.

Comment: @AdamDavisKD8OAS: Good point, I've removed selecting it since it doesn't match the question.

Answer (score 4):

There are a number of sites attempting to document HF digital band plans.  You'll have to poke around a bit, though, since people are experimenting.

An internet search for "HF digital band plan" will provide new links as the following links go stale or change URL:

- http://www.arrl.org/band-plan
- http://www.bandplans.com/?band=All
- http://sharon.esrac.ele.tue.nl/dxpress/downloads/bandplannew.pdf

Comment: This is not the best answer because all it contains are links. Consider quoting some of the info from the links you mention. Otherwise its a great answer.

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out by @Michael Kjörling, the answer is different for different regions of the world. The DARC (German HAM Radio Club) published a rather good [overview over the *preference frequencies* for different digimodes on the HF bands](http://www.darc.de/referate/hf/digitale-betriebsarten/vorzugsfrequenzen/) valid for the **[IARU Region 1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Amateur_Radio_Union#IARU_Region_1)** (Africa, Europe, Middle East, northern Asia):

- **CW**: 1'810-1'838, 3'500-3'580, 7'000-7'040, 10'100-10'140, 14'000-14'070, 18'068-18'095, 21'000-21'070, 24'890-24'915 & 28'000-28'070 kHz
- **PSK31**: 1'838, 3'580, 7'040<sup>#</sup>, 10'140, 14'070, 18'100, 21'080, 24'920 & 28'120 kHz; 1 KHz bandwidth (e.g. 10'140-10'141 kHz) for QRP, +2 kHz (e.g. >10'142 kHz) for PSK63 & PSK125
- **MFSK16**: 1'838-1'842, 3'583-3'600, 7'043-7'050, 10'143-10'150, 14'080-14'099, 18'103-18'109, 21'080-21'120, 24'923-24'929 & 28'080-28'150 kHz
- **Olivia**<sup>+</sup>: 1'843, 3'583, 7'043, 10'143, 14'073, 18'103, 21'073, 24'923 & 28'123 kHz (bandwidth < 500 Hz); 14'107.5 kHz (Olivia 32/1000)
- **WSPR**: 1'836.6, 3'592.6, 5'287.2, 7'038.6, 10'138.7, 14'095.6, 18'104.6, 21'094.6, 24'924.6 & 28'124.6 kHz
- **Hell**<sup>+</sup>: 3'584, 7'044, 10'144<sup>§</sup>, 14'074, 18'104, 21'074, 24'924 & 28'074 kHz
- **Fax**: 3'735 & 7'165, 14'230, 18'110, 21'340, 24'930 & 28'680 kHz (partially also used by SSTV)
- **SSTV**: 3'735, 7'165, 14'230, 21'340 & 28'680 kHz (also used by FAX)
- **Digital-SSTV**: 3'733, 7'173, 14'233, 18'1625 & 21'340 kHz
- **FreeDV**: 7'190 & 14'236 kHz

---

<sup>#</sup> It's recommended to use frequencies above 7040 kHz (40m band goes up to 7200 KHz) for digimodes, as 7000-7040 kHz is reserved for CW.

<sup>+</sup> center frequency

<sup>§</sup> Used by the Aurora-Bake DK0WCY, too.